# how to give a null value to onPanEnd while making a drawpad using custom painter

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector, custom-painter

```
onPanEnd: (details) {
          pointsList.add(null);
          
          pointsStream.add(pointsList);
           },

class DrawModel {
  final Offset offset;
  final Paint paint;
  

      DrawModel({required this.offset, required this.paint});

}
```

Error:The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DrawModel

Comment: What is the data type of `pointList`?

Comment: List<DrawModel> pointsList = [];
  final pointsStream = BehaviorSubject<List<DrawModel>>();

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/70983034/11452511

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
List<DrawModel?> pointList = [];
```